# AES encrypted string from objective C is not decrypted by Java decrypt function

Tags: java, objective-c, encryption, aes, pbkdf2

Hi i have encrypted a string using BBAES library in objective C . After which i passed it to server through webservices . But i keep on getting this error from server , error = "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $"

I am able to decrypt that string locally with same library but Java decryption is throwing this error. (This code decrypts correctly when encrypted string sent from Android)

JAVA settings and function:

```
/** The Constant PASS_PHRASE. */
private static final String PASS_PHRASE = "PASS";

/** The Constant ITERATION_COUNT. */
private static final int ITERATION_COUNT = 1000;

/** The Constant KEY_SIZE. */
private static final int KEY_SIZE = 128;

/**
 * Instantiates a new aes util.
 */
public AesUtil() {
    this.keySize = KEY_SIZE;
    this.iterationCount = ITERATION_COUNT;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        throw fail(e);
    }
}

 /**
 * Decrypt.
 *
 * @param salt
 *            the salt
 * @param iv
 *            the iv
 * @param passphrase
 *            the passphrase
 * @param ciphertext
 *            the ciphertext
 * @return the string
 */
public String decrypt(String salt, String iv, String passphrase, String ciphertext) {
    try {
        SecretKey key = generateKey(salt, passphrase);
        byte[] decrypted = doFinal(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv, base64(ciphertext));
        return new String(decrypted, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw fail(e);
    }
}

 /**
 * Generate key.
 *
 * @param salt
 *            the salt
 * @param passphrase
 *            the passphrase
 * @return the secret key
 */
private SecretKey generateKey(String salt, String passphrase) {
    try {
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passphrase.toCharArray(), hex(salt), iterationCount, keySize);
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(), "AES");
        return key;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        throw fail(e);
    }
}

 /**
 * Random.
 *
 * @param length
 *            the length
 * @return the string
 */
public static String random(int length) {
    byte[] salt = new byte[length];
    new SecureRandom().nextBytes(salt);
    return hex(salt);
}
```

IOS code :

```
// BBAESSaltDefaultLength = 16 bytes
NSData* salt = [BBAES randomDataWithLength:BBAESSaltDefaultLength];
// BBAESPBKDF2DefaultIterationsCount = 1000 , keysize = 128
NSData *key = [BBAES keyBySaltingPassword:@"PASS" salt:salt keySize:BBAESKeySize128  numberOfIterations:BBAESPBKDF2DefaultIterationsCount];  

NSString *secretMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"cli\":\"%@\",\"work\":\"%@\"}",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"cli"],[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"work"]]; 
NSLog(@"Original message: %@", secretMessage);

NSData *BBIV = [BBAES randomIV];

NSData *encryptedBBData = [BBAES encryptedDataFromData:data IV:BBIV key:key options:BBAESEncryptionOptionsIncludeIV]; // This generates 64 byts

NSString *encryptedBBString =  [secretMessage bb_AESEncryptedStringForIV:BBIV key:key options:BBAESEncryptionOptionsIncludeIV];
NSLog(@"Encrypted message: %@", encryptedBBString);

NSString *decryptedMessage = [encryptedBBString bb_AESDecryptedStringForIV:nil key:key]; 
NSLog(@"Decrypted message: %@", decryptedMessage);

NSString *saltBBString = salt.hexadecimalString;
NSString *IVBBString = BBIV.hexadecimalString; 

[request setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"id\":\"%@\",\"mx_id\":\"%@\",\"payload\":\"%@\"}",IVBBString,saltBBString,encryptedBBString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

What might be wrong ? Can you please help me out ?

EDIT :

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; NSString *authString = [@"Bearer " stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"jwtAuthToken"] ];
[request setValue:authString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[request setValue:@"mobile" forHTTPHeaderField:@"source"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: Can you show us the full text of the error?

Comment: This is the error i receive on iOS side . The data is {
    error = "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $";

Comment: That sounds like a marshaling error.  Like the data you're writing to the stream isn't correct, and has nothing to do with the encryption.  Can we see the network code on both sides?  And how you call it on the sending side.

Comment: @markspace have added the network code from ios